# Why are not some of the constant fields in java enum values?

Tags: java, enums, constants

The documentation about the [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/ScrollPane.html) uses no enum values for the scrollbar policy (and neither does any other class for constant field values), is there a reason for that?

Is there a more in depth meaning of the values for these constant field values or are they just in ascending order? Because in my opinion having a constructor like `public ScrollPane(int scrollbarDisplayPolicy)` looks not as meaningful as for example `public ScrollPane(ScrollPane.ScrollbarDisplayPolicy scrollbarDisplayPolicy)`

Or is this just to have not multiple enums with only a few values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: `enum`s were only introduced in [Java 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) and these constants are older than that.

Unfortunately there is no way to retro-fit the API without breaking code compatibility. (Retro-fitting an API for new features sounds an impossible task in general, but an example of when this was possible is the introduction of generics, also in Java 5.)

Comment: Do you know if they use enums for classes they have added after enums were introduced or do they still stick to the old way?

Comment: @Marcono1234 No, they stick to the old way as far as I can tell, for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayer.html#getScrollableBlockIncrement-java.awt.Rectangle-int-int-). But in entirely new APIs, like JavaFX, enums are very much the norm.

Answer (score 2):

Java [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) was introduced in version 1.5.

So most of the libraries which was developed before java 1.5 uses, `static final` constants.

For example, log4j [levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) are also public static final values of integer value.

Comment: And `java.util.logging`, introduced in 1.4, uses the pre-Java 5 typesafe enum class idiom.